# Three.js interleaved geometry type

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, webgl

I was looking into performance optimizations.
In the current time I use `BufferGeometry` for my models, but found interesting demo with interleaved geometry type, which gives much more FPS.

In test with 150k cubes, the results are:

- [Interleaved BufferGeometry](http://benaadams.github.io/three.js/examples/webgl_interleavedbuffergeometry.html) - 45fps
- [AlteredQualia BufferGeometry](http://alteredqualia.com/three/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_perf2.html) - 20fps

What is the main difference between them ?

Comment: Hmm, the interleavedGEometry-Demo says something about 15.000 cubes, AlteredQualia Buffer -Demo  is 150,000 cubes. This would at least explain the performance difference

Comment: you can change cube count from 15K to 600K in interleavedGEometry-Demo [drop-down in right top corner]

Comment: Ah, sorry, did not see that :) Thx. Well, maybe it's just the better structure but maybe dependent on the hardware below? 
maybe like explained here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3ddrawing/conceptual/opengles_programmingguide/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData.html

Anyway, i am just speculating, sorry :)